# Launch sublime text 3 from terminal and build with activated conda environment

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3, virtualenv, conda

I am new to macOS and I am having issues using conda env from sublime.
Lets imagine I created a conda environment named "myenv"

In linux, I was able to activate `myenv` in terminal and launch sublime text 3 and my code would compile with the activated environment.

The sequence of terminal commands I would run

`conda evn -n "myenv" python=3
source activate myenv
subl .`

However, in macOS, when I try the same thing, sublime refers back to the root anaconda and builds with the root anaconda directory.

Can someone help me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a separate `.sublime-build` for your `conda` environment.

Go to **Tools → Build System → New Build System** and copy this to it.

```
{
    "cmd": ["your-path-to-the-conda-env", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Save it in `Packages/User` and try to build now.

( Your path to the conda environment can be found out using `which python3` while your environment is active )

Comment: Do I have to repeat this process every time I want to use a different environment?

Comment: Once you save the build system you can use it for your programs.

Comment: @JoongGonYim Thank you comments are not allowed; accepting the answer and/or upvoting it is what is allowed. I deleted your thank you comment!